# Uniqueness of homology functor from pairs of polyhedra

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In my book it is written the following theorem

> Suppose that $H$ and $H'$ are exact homotopic functors from the category of pairs of polyhedra to the category of sequences of Abelian groups that satisfies the excision axiom and the dimension axiom. Suppose that there exists a natural trasformation of $H$ to $H'$ such that the morphism corresponding to the point is an isomorphism. Then these functors are equivalent.

In the proof of this theorem it is used that $H_0(S^n)=\mathbb{Z}$ if $n>0$ and $H_0(S^0)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$. How can I deduce these properties from the axioms?

(I suspect that the book forgot to include the additivity axiom from the Eilenberg–Steenrod axioms, but I can be wrong!)